# Matching any character except an underscore using Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write Regex that will match a string of characters EXCEPT strings with an underscore.

I have this so far `/[A-Za-z0-9]+/` but I don't know what to include in it to make it require no underscore.

UPDATE:

Is should have made this more clear off the bat. 
I am trying to match an email address, but not email addresses that have an underscore in the portion after the _

This is what I have in total so far.
`/[A-Za-z_0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.(com|ca|org|net)/`
The answers as of yet, don't work

Comment: `^[^_]+$` this means any string without an underscore.  e.g., this comment or your whole question.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for - matching strings of characters, except for strings of characters that contain an underscore - this requires regex lookahead.

The reason is that regular expressions normally operate one character at a time. So if I want to know if I should match a character, but only if there is not an underscore later, I need to use lookahead.

`^((?!_)[A-Za-z0-9])+$`

`?!` is the negative lookahead operator

EDIT:

So you want there to be at most one underscore in the portion before the @ sign, and no underscore in the portion after?

`^[A-Za-z0-9]+_?[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.(com|ca|org|net)$`

Comment: How does this ensure no underscore after the @?

Comment: Because the character group [A-Za-z0-9] does not contain the underscore character, and consequently underscores won't match. The only valid strings after the @ sign are one or more characters, followed by a period, followed by one of (com|ca|org|net).

Comment: If you aren't already, I recommend a site such as [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com) to test your regular expressions against test strings.

Answer (score 17):

`/^[^_]+$/` would match a string of 1 or more character containing any character except underscore.